# Appending symbol code to HTML from a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append a html symbol code - ☀ which is a sun to an html span.innerHTML using a js function but what I get in is

```html
<span class="condition symbol">&amp;#x2600;</span>
```

And in this way it shows ☀ instead of the sun symbol.

I tried using ``, '',"" while appending the symbol's code but same.

```js
const htmlElement=document.createElement('span');
... //adding the classes
htmlElement.textContent='&#x2600;';
```

Comment: Typo?  Looks like you just forgot the `&` before the unicode HTML entity, like you have before the ampersand HTML entity?

Comment: what's your javascript code look like?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to provide all the information necessary for us to understand the problem.

Comment: Use `innerHTML`, not `textContent`. Just like you said in the first sentence. `textContent` doesn't parse HTML, it inserts the string literally.

Comment: Indeed! That was the problem. I wrote that I am using innerHTML but acutally I was using textContent! That solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use innerHTML to display the symbol.
Or you can also use textContent and set the hexadecimal content like this

```
    const htmlElement = document.createElement('span');
    htmlElement.textContent = "\u2600";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` to render the symbol.

```js
const htmlElement=document.createElement('span');
//adding the classes
htmlElement.innerHTML='&#x2600;';
document.body.append(htmlElement);
```

Comment: They said they're trying to add it in JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to add it in JS.

Comment: Also I tried to replace &amp;#x2600; with &#x2600; but no result.

Comment: run again, it works with `innerHTML`

Comment: Did so and worked!